# How can I check to see if any values in an array show a value of true with an if statement?

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
var myObj = 
{"qId":"726112",
 "text":"xx",
 "answers":[{"answerId":null,
             "answerUId":1,
             "text":"xx",
             "correct":null,
             "response":false},
            {"answerId":null,
             "answerUId":2,
             "text":"xx",
             "correct":null,
             "response":false},
            {"answerId":null,
             "answerUId":4,
             "text":"xx",
             "correct":null,
             "response":false}]}
```

Can someone tell me how I can use an if statement to check if any one of the response fields has a value of true?

Comment: cant get ur requirement, please clarify, what do u mean by check if any one of the response fields has a value of true

Comment: The object has a property called answers which has an array of objects. If any of the response properties in those arrays has a value of true. That's what I need to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function, which returns `true` if atleast one of the elements return `true`, like this

```
if (myObj.answers.some(function(answer) { return answer.response; })) {
    # Atleast one of them is true
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2R9JY/)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to find is it true or false change status of response in Array . you can easily understood.

var myObj = 
{"qId":"726112",

"text":"xx",

"answers":
[{"answerId":null,
             "answerUId":1,
             "text":"xx",
             "correct":null,
             "response":true},

```
        {"answerId":null,
         "answerUId":2,
         "text":"xx",
         "correct":null,
         "response":false},

        {"answerId":null,
         "answerUId":4,
         "text":"xx",
         "correct":null,
         "response":true}]
};
```

if(myObj.answers.length > 0){

```
for (var i in myObj.answers){

    if(myObj.answers[i].response){
        console.log(i+"th  index of answers Array in myObj object has   "+myObj.answers[i].response);
    }
    else{

    console.log(i+"th  index of answers Array in myObj object has   "+myObj.answers[i].response);

    }
}
```

}

output :

0th  index of answers Array in myObj object has   true

1th  index of answers Array in myObj object has   false

2th  index of answers Array in myObj object has   true

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea and formatting the code and output would be helpful.